# Sump Pump Turn On Height and Cycling

Tags: tile, drain, pump, sump

I live in a new home that is 2 years old.  During construction the builder put in both interior and exterior drain tiles feeding two sump pits.  The area has a high water table at times due to some underground streams nearby so the builder was being extra precautious when building the home. The basement is full and finished.  One of the sump pits is at the end of the house, the other in the center along the same wall. They expel water into an underground storm water basin around 15 feet away from the house

The sump pits themselves are 24" deep and 19" wide.  The top of the 4" inlet pipe is 6" below the basement floor.  The pumps are Zoeller with fixed vertical float.  They are set at the bottom of the pit on blocks.  The turn on level of the the pump is 16" below the basement floor and 6" below the bottom of the inlet pipe.

For nearly two years we never even saw water in the sump pits but during the recent 90 day stretch on the NJ shore we are at a 90% above normal and they finally started to have water in them.  The water sticks around for a few weeks and the recedes to nothing and the pits are dry

The basins are perforated and we have never had any actual water come through any of the inlet pipes of either pit.  The water is all coming through the perforations in the sump pit.  At the peak condition one of the pumps cycles every 30 seconds and the other every 2 minutes.  When I shut the pumps off - the water stabilizes to around 1.5" below the inlet drain.

So here is my question.  It seems like I have the sump pumps set too low and I am just pumping ground water. Eventually when the ground water goes down they cycle slower and then stop altogether.  I was thinking that since the inlets themselves have never had water in them that I'm needlessly pumping water and could raise it to around the bottom of the inlet tile which would be 10" below the basement floor?  I also thought about getting a pump with variable on/off levels versus my fixed ones.

Alternatively in the two years we've been here the pumps may have been on for 6 weeks total - and this was due to super abnormally high precipitation over the last 3 months.  When they are on they are noisy - so ideally would like to slow the cycle if possible without risking water in the basement.

Comment: If the pump float is non-adjustable, you could power the pump through an independent float switch that could be set wherever you like.

Comment: Your solution has the added benefit that if you ever do have a flood so bad the inlet pipes start emitting water, your pumps will only have to fight *that* water, rather than work a probably 100% duty cycle in a futile effort to move an infinite supply of ground water.    I think another way to view this is that your pits are too deep; they should not extend down into the water table unnecessarily.   Deep pits are useful in the OPPOSITE situation from yours: Above the water table, with a trickle of water from the inlet pipes, they reduce duty cycle by collecting water.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 high flow pumps which should be able to quickly lower incoming water.

Do you have high water alarms?

I'd get the HC6000 hi/low pump controller.  You can set the on and off point for the pump.  Ideally you want the pump to cycle as infrequently as possible and to your point having some water sitting in the sump isn't a huge deal as long as the incoming water doesn't exceed the ability of your pumps to remove it.  Setting the on mark to the bottom of the inlet pipe should be fine.

Even with the existing pump and fixed float, you can just plug that into the HC6000 controller and it won't have the ability to turn on until the on point has been reached.

Your biggest issue is likely to be that without somewhat regular use a pump can seize but you have two pumps so that should be a pretty good backup.  I'd probably just a put a yearly test the pumps into my calendar.  My pumps run daily and I've also got a PumpSpy 1500W with a marine battery in case I loose power - power outages tend to happen during storm / rain events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - sounds like exactly what I need